# Change Power Query regional settings with VBA

Tags: vba, powerquery

I would like to change Excel Query options with VBA. Particularly I would like to change Regional Settings
[(see screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QF3U0.png)
Does anyone know how can I do it with VBA?

Answer (score 0):

This is currently unsupported through VBA.